# Using eval to println elements of library-dependencies in SBT 0.12.x shell

Tags: scala, sbt

*Trying to master SBT and Scala makes my live tough at times when simple things in theory turn themselves into not so simple in practise.*

I'm working with [Apache Spark](https://spark.incubator.apache.org/) **0.9.0-incubating** that uses SBT **0.12.4**.

While poking around in their SBT build configuration I ran across an issue of how to `println` elements of `library-dependencies` in SBT (interactive) shell. It's a more general question of how to `eval` more complex Scala expressions in sbt shell?

```
> external-mqtt/library-dependencies
[info] List(org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.3, io.netty:netty-all:4.0.13.Final, org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:7.6.8.v20121106, org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:2.5.0.v201103041518, org.scalatest:scalatest:1.9.1:test, org.scalacheck:scalacheck:1.10.0:test, com.novocode:junit-interface:0.9:test, org.easymock:easymock:3.1:test, org.mockito:mockito-all:1.8.5:test, commons-io:commons-io:2.4:test, commons-io:commons-io:2.4, org.eclipse.paho:mqtt-client:0.4.0)
```

I managed to do the following

```
> eval libraryDependencies in externalMqtt
[info] ans: sbt.SettingKey[Seq[sbt.ModuleID]] = sbt.Scoped$$anon$1@aa3170e
```

but am struggling with getting the `Seq[sbt.ModuleID]` out of `sbt.SettingKey`.

A concise explanation on how to proceed would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of you using `eval`, if you first drop into:

```
consoleProject
```

then you can attach `.eval` to settings, so e.g.

```
> consoleProject
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
import sbt._
import Keys._
import currentState._
import extracted._
import cpHelpers._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).

scala> (fullClasspath in Compile).eval.foreach(println)
Attributed(/Users/tisue/Dropbox/repos/euler/target/scala-2.10/classes)
Attributed(/Users/tisue/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar)
```

This doesn't answer your question directly; I don't know how to make `eval` do what you want. As documented at http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Console-Project.html , and as actually visible in the above transcript, `consoleProject` does a number of imports that bring useful names and implicits into scope, which is what makes the above work.  You might expect that `eval` would evaluate code you pass it in a context where the same identifiers and implicits are in scope, but it doesn't. (I tried putting the same imports into a call into `eval` but it didn't work.)

Not the greatest answer — perhaps someone else can be more authoritative.

Comment: You say 0.12, I'm using 0.13, not sure if it matters.

Comment: Yeah, I knew about `consoleProject` and the goodies it brings to the table, but thought it could've been a way to make `eval` more pleasant, too. I accept your answer even though *"This doesn't answer your question directly"*. Thanks Seth!